# math mode in missing $ error

Tags: math-mode

how can correct the error of missing $ inserted

```
\begin{equation*}


$ V^{(b)}_{i} $ = 
\begin{cases}

 1, & \text{ if the bus b visits stop i }. \\
 0, & \text {otherwise} 

\end{cases}  
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Remove the blank lines and the `$`'s

Comment: you should remove the `$` as `equation` has already started math mode, and remove the blank lines which are not allowed in math mode, not a tex error but `bus b visits stop i` should be `bus $b$ visits stop $i$`

Answer (score 0):

An `equation` environment should not contain any blank lines.  In tex blank lines signal the start of a new paragraph and that is not allowed within in an `equation`.  Furthermore the content of `equation` is already in math mode, so you do not want to switch out of math mode via `$` for symbols such as `V^{(b)}_i`. 
In the other hand in the conditions for the cases, you are inside a `\text` command and need to write `$b$` and `$i$` it get those symbols in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 V^{(b)}_{i}  =
 \begin{cases}
   1, & \text{if the bus $b$ visits stop $i$,} \\
   0, & \text {otherwise.}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

If you use `mathtools` rather than/on top of `amsmath` then there is the convenient `dcases*` environment where the `\text` command is automatically used for the side conditions (and the first part is set as displayed math):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 V^{(b)}_{i}  =
 \begin{dcases*}
   1, &if the bus $b$ visits stop $i$, \\
   0, &otherwise.
 \end{dcases*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```